# Is it possible to show 2 Frames at the same time?

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, jpanel

So I'm working on a little quiz. It's finished but I'm still adding some stuff into it. Everytime a question appears i want to add a timer onto it that has a countdown. I've created that countdown seperatly and now I'm trying to add it to the different frames.

My question is, if it's possible to add a frame (timer) onto another frame (questions+ answers)?

I did everything with JFrames!

**Here is the code for the countdown:**

```
 public class timer extends JFrame {

    public timer() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new TestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class TestPane extends JPanel {
    JLabel label;
    Timer timer;
    int count;
    public TestPane() {
        label = new JLabel("...");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(label);
        timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                count++;
                if (count < 100000) {

                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException error){
                    }

                    label.setText(Integer.toString(count));

                } else {
                    ((Timer) (e.getSource())).stop();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you have wrong name for the `Timer` class?

```
public class Timer extends JFrame {

    public Timer() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new TestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

You create new instance of `Timer` in your `TestPane` code, but your class name is `timer` see?